# WPF ComboBox TextChanged event overrides navigation

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox, textchanged

I'm using ComboBox for searching in database.

Event in XAML:  `TextBoxBase.TextChanged="text_changed"`
Event in C#: `text_changed` retrive data into DataTable thru SQL query and populates collection of combobox items thru **ItemsSource** property.

Now, when i typing or pasting text into my combobox (if matches founds)
combobox shows DropDown list.

First problem is that i'm trying navigate to them by using keyboard arrow buttons, but TextChanged event fires again and fist item will be chosen.

Second problem is that when i erase incorrect typed symbol by backspace and database match increases, in this moment all of my typed text markup as selected..

Thanks for attention :-)

Comment: Your arrow keys are defined as symbols in textchanged event you can make event if arrow buttons clicked texbox should loose focus. That should fix your first problem.

Comment: @Bensinaspa if i navigate up or down by combobox items list, it puts current highlited value on "main field" (upper, body of combobox). It's defaut future of a combobox. I mean, maybe textchange event and items scrolling uncompatible and i must to use another way to retive items collection, another event..